# multiple URL checking in a single Cloudwatch Synthetics Canary with python

Tags: python, amazon-web-services, selenium-webdriver, amazon-cloudwatch

I want to check multiple (100+) URLs in a single CloudWatch Synthetics Canary. I start my script from this blog post:
https://aws.amazon.com/blogs/mt/create-canaries-in-python-and-selenium-using-amazon-cloudwatch-synthetics/

But with some minor modification i got the following error:

```
TypeError: 'NoneType' object is not callable
ERROR: Canary execution exception.Traceback (most recent call last):
File "/var/task/index.py", line 74, in handle_canary response = await customer_canary.handler(event, context) 
File "/opt/python/bm_check.py", line 36, in handler return await main() File "/opt/python/bm_check.py", line 28, in main await webdriver.execute_step("Navigate to home", navigate_to_home(url)) 
File "/opt/python/aws_synthetics/core/base_synthetics.py", line 231, in execute_step return_value = function_to_execute()
```

My canary script:

```
from selenium.webdriver.support.ui import WebDriverWait
from selenium.webdriver.support import expected_conditions as EC
from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By
import selenium.common.exceptions
from aws_synthetics.selenium import synthetics_webdriver as webdriver
from aws_synthetics.common import synthetics_logger as logger
from aws_synthetics.common import synthetics_configuration

TIMEOUT = 5


async def main():
    browser = webdriver.Chrome()

    synthetics_configuration.set_config(
        {
            "screenshot_on_step_start": False,
            "screenshot_on_step_success": True,
            "screenshot_on_step_failure": True
        }
    )
    
    def navigate_to_home(url):
        browser.implicitly_wait(TIMEOUT)
        browser.get(url)
    
    url = "https://d2h3ljlsmzojxz.cloudfront.net/"
    await webdriver.execute_step("Navigate to home", navigate_to_home(url))

    url = "youtube.com"
    await webdriver.execute_step("Navigate to home", navigate_to_home(url))
    
    logger.info("---------Finished the execution---------")
    
async def handler(event, context):
    return await main()
```

My final goal is to check these URLs with a for loop, and see every single URL as an execution step, taking screenshots on success and failure.
What am i doing wrong?

Thanks in advance!

EDIT:
I cunsulted with an aws partner and helped me found a solution.
The http(s) protocol is necessary to use in the url.
My working script:

```
from selenium.webdriver.support.ui import WebDriverWait
from selenium.webdriver.support import expected_conditions as EC
from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By
import selenium.common.exceptions
from aws_synthetics.selenium import synthetics_webdriver as webdriver
from aws_synthetics.common import synthetics_logger as logger
from aws_synthetics.common import synthetics_configuration

TIMEOUT = 5


async def main():
    browser = webdriver.Chrome()

    synthetics_configuration.set_config(
        {
        "screenshot_on_step_start": False,
        "screenshot_on_step_success": True,
        "screenshot_on_step_failure": True
        }
    )

    def navigate_to_home():
        browser.implicitly_wait(TIMEOUT)
        browser.get(url)
    
    url_list = [
        "https://d2h3ljlsmzojxz.cloudfront.net/",
        "https://youtube.com"
    ]

    for index, url in enumerate(url_list):
        await webdriver.execute_step("URL check {}".format(index), navigate_to_home)

    logger.info("---------Finished the execution---------")

    
async def handler(event, context):
    return await main()
```

Answer (score 2):

You current code is trying to use the value returned by `navigate_to_home(url)` as the callback function. Here that value is `None`.

Instead try the following which ensures the correct callback function is passed in:

`await webdriver.execute_step("Navigate to home", lambda: navigate_to_home(url))`